# Socket Programming. Server client communication

Tags: java, sockets

I want a Server Client communication via socket programming in java. But problem arises when i try to pass something to client using printWriter's out object i have to use out.Println("...") which prints every thing on clients console;
i want to send information to client without printing it on client's conole. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a stream other than System.out according to your needs. Here are a few to choose from:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Datagram Socket on server & client. The link below is a huge help.

http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/